# Is this matrix multiplication and derivative correct?

Tags: calculus

Consider the following:
$$\displaystyle (\textbf{Y}-\textbf{X} \beta)^{T}(\textbf{Y}-\textbf{X} \beta) = \textbf{Y}^{T} \textbf{Y}- \textbf{Y}^{T} \textbf{X} \beta-\textbf{X}^{T} \beta^{T} \textbf{Y}+\textbf{X}^{T} \beta^{T}\textbf{X} \beta$$

Also consider the derivative of this: $-\textbf{Y}^{T} \textbf{X}-\textbf{X}^{T}\textbf{Y}+2 \textbf{X}^{T}  \textbf{X} \beta= 0$

Are these two expressions correct? I want to solve for $\beta$.

Comment: Is $\beta$ also a matrix? Or a scalar number?

Answer (score 1):

Because $\beta$ appears to be a scalar, you should write $\beta$ instead of $\beta^T$. Otherwise the calculation is ok. Note that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.